# UIView is not showing in UIScrollView programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have a UIView container inside UIScrollView. but it not showing in scrollview. when I check in debug view hierarchy the width is ambiguous. here I show the pic and my code setup.

[image: uiview]

```
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.contentSize.height   = 1000
        scrollView.backgroundColor      = #colorLiteral(red: 0.968627451, green: 0.968627451, blue: 0.968627451, alpha: 1)
        scrollView.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, trailing: view.trailingAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, leading: view.leadingAnchor, topPadding: 0, rightPadding: 0, bottomPadding: 0, leftPadding: 0, width: 0, height: 0)

        scrollView.addSubview(navigationView)
        navigationView.addSubview(titleLbl)
        navigationView.addSubview(profileIV)

        navigationView.backgroundColor  = .red

        navigationView.anchor(top: scrollView.topAnchor, trailing: scrollView.trailingAnchor, bottom: nil, leading: scrollView.leadingAnchor, topPadding: 0, rightPadding: 0, bottomPadding: 0, leftPadding: 0, width: 0, height: 200)

        titleLbl.anchor(top: navigationView.topAnchor, trailing: nil, bottom: nil, leading: navigationView.leadingAnchor, topPadding: 40, rightPadding: 0, bottomPadding: 0, leftPadding: 16, width: 50, height: 23)

        profileIV.anchor(top: navigationView.topAnchor, trailing: nil, bottom: nil, leading: nil, topPadding: 80, rightPadding: 0, bottomPadding: 0, leftPadding: 0, width: 68, height: 68)
        profileIV.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

        profileNameLbl.anchor(top: profileIV.bottomAnchor, trailing: nil, bottom: nil, leading: nil, topPadding: 10, rightPadding: 0, bottomPadding: 0, leftPadding: 0, width: 0, height: 27)
        profileNameLbl.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going through programmatic way . ok here it is try using this

```
open class BaseScrollViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var contentViewSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height + 100)

    lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let view = UIScrollView(frame: .zero)
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.frame = self.view.bounds
        view.contentSize = contentViewSize
        return view
    }()

    lazy var containerView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = .clear
        v.frame.size = contentViewSize
        return v
    }()

    override open func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubviews(scrollView)
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

        scrollView.addSubview(containerView)
        setupContainer(containerView)
    }

    public func setupContainer(_ container: UIView) {

    }
}
```

usage :

```
class ClientScrollViewController: BaseScrollViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func setupContainer(_ container: UIView) {
        //add your views here
    }
}
```

Comment: hey thank you @RishabhShukla it works. I think I need to analyse why your code is work, since I think the regular code like my code setup usually work. like view.addSubview(scrollView) and scrollView.addSubview(someView)

Answer (score 1):

You must change your code to :

//your scroll view

[image]

//your navigationView

[image]

[image]

And add to `yourViewController : UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate`

At `viewDidLoad :`

```
yourScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: yourNavigationView.frame.width, height: yourNavigationView.frame.height)
    scroll.delegate = self
```

After then do whatever you want inside of your navigationView.

In addition, you can add this code if needs :

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView == scroll{
        if scrollView.contentOffset.x != 0 {
            scrollView.contentOffset.x = 0
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: hi @Picode it work actually, but it's not what I want. Is it any better way for doing this? I like my navigation height is 200 while the navigation view inside the scrollview. so I can scroll the navigationView

Comment: Set your navigationView's height to 200 :)

Comment: I did but, the outcome is the navigationView is not scrolling. @Picode :)